# MATLAB LIBSVM installation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I was going to install libSVM in MATLAB and downloaded the file.

But in MATLAB there already seems to be functions, `svmtrain`,`svmpredict` and so on. Does MATLAB already come with LIBSVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MATLAB has a [statistics and machine-learning toolbox](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) which is not LIBSVM, but does the same thing.

Note that it is not a free package which comes with MATLAB. You can check whether you have it installed by calling [`ver`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html), which on my PC results in:

```
ver
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
MATLAB License Number:
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional  Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.5        (R2015a)
Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.5.1      (R2015a)
Communications System Toolbox                         Version 6.0        (R2015a)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 6.2        (R2015a)
Control System Toolbox                                Version 9.9        (R2015a)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.5.1      (R2015a)
DO Qualification Kit                                  Version 2.5        (R2015a)
DSP System Toolbox                                    Version 9.0        (R2015a)
Data Acquisition Toolbox                              Version 3.7        (R2015a)
Database Toolbox                                      Version 5.2.1      (R2015a)
Datafeed Toolbox                                      Version 5.1        (R2015a)
Econometrics Toolbox                                  Version 3.2        (R2015a)
Embedded Coder                                        Version 6.8        (R2015a)
Filter Design HDL Coder                               Version 2.9.7      (R2015a)
Financial Instruments Toolbox                         Version 2.1        (R2015a)
Financial Toolbox                                     Version 5.5        (R2015a)
Fixed-Point Designer                                  Version 5.0        (R2015a)
Fuzzy Logic Toolbox                                   Version 2.2.21     (R2015a)
Global Optimization Toolbox                           Version 3.3.1      (R2015a)
HDL Coder                                             Version 3.6        (R2015a)
HDL Verifier                                          Version 4.6        (R2015a)
IEC Certification Kit                                 Version 3.5        (R2015a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.9        (R2015a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.2        (R2015a)
Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 3.7        (R2015a)
LTE System Toolbox                                    Version 2.0        (R2015a)
MATLAB Coder                                          Version 2.8        (R2015a)
MATLAB Compiler                                       Version 6.0        (R2015a)
MATLAB Compiler SDK                                   Version 6.0        (R2015a)
MATLAB Distributed Computing Server                   Version 6.6        (R2015a)
MATLAB Report Generator                               Version 4.1        (R2015a)
Mapping Toolbox                                       Version 4.1        (R2015a)
Model Predictive Control Toolbox                      Version 5.0.1      (R2015a)
Model-Based Calibration Toolbox                       Version 4.8.1      (R2015a)
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 8.3        (R2015a)
OPC Toolbox                                           Version 3.3.3      (R2015a)
Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 7.2        (R2015a)
Parallel Computing Toolbox                            Version 6.6        (R2015a)
Partial Differential Equation Toolbox                 Version 2.0        (R2015a)
Phased Array System Toolbox                           Version 3.0        (R2015a)
Polyspace Bug Finder                                  Version 1.3        (R2015a)
Polyspace Code Prover                                 Version 9.3        (R2015a)
RF Toolbox                                            Version 2.16       (R2015a)
Robust Control Toolbox                                Version 5.3        (R2015a)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 7.0        (R2015a)
Spreadsheet Link EX                                   Version 3.2.3      (R2015a)
Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox               Version 10.0       (R2015a)
Symbolic Math Toolbox                                 Version 6.2        (R2015a)
System Identification Toolbox                         Version 9.2        (R2015a)
SystemTest                                            Version 2.6.9      (R2015a)
Trading Toolbox                                       Version 2.2        (R2015a)
Vehicle Network Toolbox                               Version 2.4        (R2015a)
Vision HDL Toolbox                                    Version 1.0        (R2015a)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.14.1     (R2015a)
```

where you can see I have the Statistics and machine learning toolbox installed.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB could come with  a statistics and machine-learning toolbox if you **pay for it**, or choose it when using Student Suite.

The main difference with the toolbox and LIBSVM it's that LIBSVM **supports multi-class classification**, which is a great advantage, especially when you have 4 or more clases.

If you need to classify between 3 or less clases, you could use the toolbox and 1vs1 aproach, instead of installing LIBSVM and overwriting the toolbox.

**UPDATE**

As is stated in the comments 2015 version of MATLAB supports multi-class classification. So the most important difference is that LIBSVM is **free**.

Comment: MATLAB's Statistics and machine learning toolbox supports multi-class classification as well since the latest overhaul in 2014. Specifically, I use it to classify 9 dimensional data into 6 classes.

Comment: If I install libsvm will it replace this. Both seem to have same function names like svmpredict and so on. Are there any other advantages of using libsvm

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan the cross-validation option is a plus (because is easier to implement in LIBSVM), but you could use another tools in Matlab to achieve the same.

Comment: The sole advantage as far as I can see is that it is free. Thus if you need to pay for a license to the official toolbox, this is the free alternative

Comment: @Adriaan I have 2014a and used it in my undergraduate project, are you sure about the support, could you give a example.

Comment: And when svmpredict is called when one will be used.. Since both Matlab and libsvm seem to have same function calls

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan LIBSVM overwrites Matlab SVM functions.

Comment: @ElberCM At one point [`svmtrain`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) was deprecated, hence the notice on the documentation page, and the new batch was implemented with multi-dimensional support. The new batch, amongst which [`templateSVM`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/templatesvm.html) was added in R2014b.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above.
In machine learning we like to use LIBSVM instead of the functions provided by matlab: It is faster and provides more options.
if you are interested in linear svm there is a specific package 'Library' for linear svm provided by the same group.